# Comparing NumPy object references

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, identity

I want to understand the NumPy behavior.

When I try to get the reference of an inner array of a NumPy array, and then compare it to the object itself, I get as returned value `False`.

Here is the example:

```
In [198]: x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
In [201]: x0 = x[0]
In [202]: x0 is x[0]
Out[202]: False
```

While on the other hand, with Python native objects, the returned is `True`.

```
In [205]: c = [[1,2,3],[1]]    
In [206]: c0 = c[0]    
In [207]: c0 is c[0]
Out[207]: True
```

My question, is that the intended behavior of NumPy? If so, what should I do if I want to create a reference of inner objects of NumPy arrays.

Comment: Careful when using that `is` test.  It compares the `id` of objects, not some sort of numeric equality.  I use it in expressions like `is None`, but rarely elsewhere.

Comment: @hpaulj, Ya, thanks, but that's what I intended to do, if I do comparison on the Numpy object references using `==` operator, the result will be about component wise operation, such as,  
`np.array([1]) == np.array([2])` will return
`array([False], dtype=bool)`

Comment: That's where `np.all` comes in handy.

Comment: You may need to ask another question, giving more of the context for which you need to reference or compare the 'inner objects' of an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 2d slicing

When I first wrote this I constructed and indexed a 1d array.  But the OP is working with a 2d array, so `x[0]` is a 'row', a slice of the original.

```
In [81]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
In [82]: arr.__array_interface__['data']
Out[82]: (181595128, False)

In [83]: x0 = arr[0,:]
In [84]: x0.__array_interface__['data']
Out[84]: (181595128, False)        # same databuffer pointer
In [85]: id(x0)
Out[85]: 2886887088
In [86]: x1 = arr[0,:]             # another slice, different id
In [87]: x1.__array_interface__['data']
Out[87]: (181595128, False)
In [88]: id(x1)
Out[88]: 2886888888
```

What I wrote earlier about slices still applies.  Indexing an individual elements, as with `arr[0,0]` works the same as with a 1d array.

This 2d arr has the same databuffer as the 1d `arr.ravel()`; the shape and strides are different.  And the distinction between `view`, `copy` and `item` still applies.

A common way of implementing 2d arrays in C is to have an array of pointers to other arrays.  `numpy` takes a different, `strided` approach, with just one flat array of data, and uses`shape` and `strides` parameters to implement the transversal.  So a subarray requires its own `shape` and `strides` as well as a pointer to the shared databuffer.

### 1d array indexing

I'll try to illustrate what is going on when you index an array:

```
In [51]: arr = np.arange(4)
```

The array is an object with various attributes such as shape, and a data buffer.  The buffer stores the data as bytes (in a C array), not as Python numeric objects.  You can see information on the array with:

```
In [52]: np.info(arr)
class:  ndarray
shape:  (4,)
strides:  (4,)
itemsize:  4
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  True
data pointer: 0xa84f8d8
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: int32
```

or

```
In [53]: arr.__array_interface__
Out[53]: 
{'data': (176486616, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (4,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
```

One has the data pointer in hex, the other decimal.  We usually don't reference it directly.

If I index an element, I get a new object:

```
In [54]: x1 = arr[1]
In [55]: type(x1)
Out[55]: numpy.int32
In [56]: x1.__array_interface__
Out[56]: 
{'__ref': array(1),
 'data': (181158400, False),
....}
In [57]: id(x1)
Out[57]: 2946170352
```

It has some properties of an array, but not all.  For example you can't assign to it.  Notice also that its 'data` value is totally different.

Make another selection from the same place - different id and different data:

```
In [58]: x2 = arr[1]
In [59]: id(x2)
Out[59]: 2946170336
In [60]: x2.__array_interface__['data']
Out[60]: (181143288, False)
```

Also if I change the array at this point, it does not affect the earlier selections:

```
In [61]: arr[1] = 10
In [62]: arr
Out[62]: array([ 0, 10,  2,  3])
In [63]: x1
Out[63]: 1
```

`x1` and `x2` don't have the same `id`, and thus won't match with `is`, and they don't use the `arr` data buffer either.  There's no record that either variable was derived from `arr`.

With `slicing` it is possible get a `view` of the original array,

```
In [64]: y = arr[1:2]
In [65]: y.__array_interface__
Out[65]: 
{'data': (176486620, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (1,),
 ....}
In [66]: y
Out[66]: array([10])
In [67]: y[0]=4
In [68]: arr
Out[68]: array([0, 4, 2, 3])
In [69]: x1
Out[69]: 1
```

It's data pointer is 4 bytes larger than `arr` - that is, it points to the same buffer, just a different spot.  And changing `y` does change `arr` (but not the independent `x1`).

I could even make a 0d view of this item

```
In [71]: z = y.reshape(())
In [72]: z
Out[72]: array(4)
In [73]: z[...]=0
In [74]: arr
Out[74]: array([0, 0, 2, 3])
```

In Python code we normally don't work with objects like this.  When we use the `c-api` or `cython` is it possible to access the data buffer directly.  `nditer` is an iteration mechanism that works with 0d objects like this (either in Python or the c-api).  In `cython` `typed memoryviews` are particularly useful for low level access.

http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.iterator.html#c.NpyIter

### elementwise ==

In response to comment, [Comparing NumPy object references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885090/comparing-numpy-object-references/43898587#comment74809004_43885090)

> np.array([1]) == np.array([2]) will return array([False], dtype=bool)

`==` is defined for arrays as an elementwise operation.  It compares the values of the respective elements and returns a matching boolean array.

If such a comparison needs to be used in a scalar context (such as an `if`) it needs to be reduced to a single value, as with `np.all` or `np.any`.

The `is` test compares object id's (not just for numpy objects).  It has limited value in practical coding.  I used it most often in expressions like `is None`, where `None` is an object with a unique id, and which does not play nicely with equality tests.

Comment: Great explanation. Got a whole bunch of ideas from it.
Will redo my basic about numpy on python once again. Hope I could create the cython interface afterward. :) 
thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have a miss understanding about Numpy arrays. You think that sub arrays in a multidimensional array in Numpy (like in Python lists) are separate objects, well, they're not.

A Numpy array, regardless of its dimension is just one object. And that's because Numpy creates the arrays at C levels and when loads them up as a python object it can't be break down to multiple objects. That makes Python to create a new object for preserving new parts when you use some attributes like `split()`, `__getitem__`, `take()` or etc., which as a mater of fact, its just the way that python abstracts the list-like behavior for Numpy arrays.

You can also check thin in real-time like following:

```
In [7]: x
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [8]: x[0] is x[0]
Out[8]: False
```

So as soon as you have an array or any mutable object that can hols other object in it you'll have a python mutable object and therefore you will lose the performance and all other Numpy array's cool features.

Also as @Imanol mentioned in comments you may want to use Numpy view objects if you want to have a memory optimized and flexible operation when you want to modify an array(s) with reference(s). `view` objects can be constructed in following two ways:

> `a.view(some_dtype)` or `a.view(dtype=some_dtype)` constructs a view of
>   the array’s memory with a different data-type. This can cause a
>   reinterpretation of the bytes of memory.
>
> `a.view(ndarray_subclass)` or `a.view(type=ndarray_subclass)` just returns
>   an instance of ndarray_subclass that looks at the same array (same
>   shape, dtype, etc.) This does not cause a reinterpretation of the
>   memory.
>
> For `a.view(some_dtype)`, if `some_dtype` has a different number of bytes
>   per entry than the previous `dtype` (for example, converting a regular
>   array to a structured array), then the behavior of the view cannot be
>   predicted just from the superficial appearance of a (shown by
>   `print(a)`). It also depends on exactly how a is stored in memory.
>   Therefore if a is C-ordered versus fortran-ordered, versus defined as
>   a slice or transpose, etc., the view may give different results.

Comment: Wow, that's make a lot sense.
Then, what should I do to create references for the inner object of NumPy array.
Is it impossible to achived?

Comment: @Nanangarsyad Yes it's impossible (if you want to have other numpy advantages as well). Check out the update.

Comment: It might be worth pointing that numpy returns *views* for sub-arrays (unless using fancy slicing hat creates a copy) and while views are created on the fly, they point to the same underlying data. Modifying a view changes the original array which makes the change apparent in any other view over the same sub-array. Thus, identity checking doesn't work with views, but they work great with data manipulation.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Indeed, thanks for note. Just updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Just for last question.
is it possible to do the comparison between NumPy object reference, if i were to use the C interface, like Cython (not sure) as the medium?
If any native C solution available please let me know.
BTW, I'm not a C expert neither a python expert, but I had some knowledge on both of them. Especially C, like its memory management and the likes. 
I'll start my own deep research, will be back here to give report for the result if any. :)

Comment: @Nanangarsyad Well I'm not 100% sure but as you might know C is not an object oriented language and if you want to make references to an object you need to use the pointers directly. And using such feature is a different task and might requires another question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's useful at this point, but `numpy.ndarray.ctypes` seems to have useful bits:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html

Used something like this (missing `dtype`, but meh):

```py
def is_same_array(a, b):
    return (a.shape == b.shape) and (a == b).all() and a.ctypes.data == b.ctypes.data
```

here:
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/a60daf899e9726daf2ca1259bb80ad2c7c9b3e3f/python/namedlist_alt.py#L111